# React Testing Library + Jest: code coverage cannot cover a method called only when not undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Ok, I couldn't find a better title for my question.

The fact is that I have something that looks like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import AppContext from "context";

const Component = () => {
    const { myMethod } = React.useContext(AppContext);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (myMethod) {
            myMethod();
        }
    });

    return (<bla bla />);
}

export default Component;
```

and in my test, I'm doing:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Component from "./index";
import AppContext from "context";

describe("Test the Component component", () => {
    it("should call the myMethod method", () => {
        const myMethod = jest.fn();
        
        render(
            <AppContext.Provider value={{ myMethod }}>
                <Component />
            </AppContext.Provider>
        );

        expect(myMethod).toBeCalled(); // Working!
    });

    it("shouldn't call the myMethod method", () => {
        const myMethod = undefined;
        
        render(
            <AppContext.Provider value={{ myMethod }}>
                <Component />
            </AppContext.Provider>
        );

        expect(myMethod).not.toBeCalled(); // Not Working!
    });
});
```

I think the code explains very well what I'm trying to do, I want to cover the case where the method myMethod is not defined and therefore, the `if (myMethod)` should result in being false and skipped as the coverage of my code says that the if statement is covered only in the case it is true (defined).

**EDIT**:
I tried both `not.toBeCalled()` and `not.toHaveBeenCalled()` and they both reply with the following error:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Of course the error does make sense since the myMethod is of type of undefined and not a jest mock but the point is that I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: have you tried `toHaveBeenCalled()` instead `toBeCalled()`?

Comment: Yes the error I got (that makes sense) is the same with both the calls:

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function.

I updated the question

Comment: Think about (or just try) what would happen _without_ that check. Then test that doesn't happen.

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe, thanks for the reply, the fact is that nothing happens in the component because the myMethod in fact is a set function that changes the value of a variable in my context that does not reflect in the actual components but others. Anyway, the code coverage blames that the if is not fully covered. Now multiply this by all the setters that I have around my app (a big app) and boom, my code coverage percentage decrease by a 5%

Comment: If it's never going to be undefined then just remove the check. If it could actually be undefined, as in your test case, _temporarily_ remove the check and see what happens if the component unconditionally tries to invoke it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way you can assert an undefined value was not called as a function.

Comment: Hey @AviCohenNehemia I was thinking the same, but maybe there is a different approach I'm not thinking of. Otherwise, the coverage wouldn't highlight it as an uncovered condition

Answer (score -1):

Okay, you want to make `myMethod` to be falsy.

This works?

```
const myMethod = jest.fn();
// make myMethod to be falsy
myMethod.mockReturnValue(false);

render(
  <AppContext.Provider value={{ myMethod }}>
      <Component />
  </AppContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, man, for the help; unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. At the moment that I mock the method, the method is no more undefined and therefor my if statement is not skipped. I want to test when the if (myMethod) is false (so myMethod is undefined) and not when it returns false. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Oh yeah you are very right. `myMethod` won't be falsy despite returning false. I can't think of any non-hack idea that would change your `Component` structure. Sry.